# Bootstrap DIVs sliding in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, slider

I am using Bootstrap to manage my UI. I have three Divs -
First div : col-lg-10.
Second div : col-lg-36.
Third div : col-lg-1. Third div has another hidden div (Inner_Third div) that has my data to display.

First and Second Divs are always visible. Third Div is collapsible and it expands (and show() Inner_Third div) based on a hyperlink  click from Second div.

I am able to expand the Third div (and show() the Inner_Third div) with ease. But I am stuck when I am again collapsing the Third div (and hide() Inner_Third div) again. The hide() of Inner_Third div happens before the collapsing starts and I want it to hide() after the collapse.

Collapsed State :
First div : col-lg-10.
Second div : col-lg-36.
Third div : col-lg-1 (with Inner_Third div hidden).

Expanded State :
First div : col-lg-10.
Second div : col-lg-19.
Third div : col-lg-19 (with Inner_Third div visible).

Below is my One Page code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-10" style="height:300px;background-color: #FA5D4E" id="content">
            <h2>Getting started</h2>
            <p>
                ASP.NET MVC gives you a powerful, patterns-based way to build dynamic websites that
                enables a clean separation of concerns and gives you full control over markup
                for enjoyable, agile development.
            </p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301865">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-36" style="background-color:yellow;height:300px" id="menu1">            
            <h2>Get more libraries</h2>
            <p>NuGet is a free Visual Studio extension that makes it easy to add, remove, and update libraries and tools in Visual Studio projects.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301866">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
            <a href="#" id="showDetailsSection">Details</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1" style="background-color:blue;height:300px;padding:0px" id="menu2">
            <div id="menu2Div" style="display:none;background-color:green;overflow:auto;margin:0px;height:300px;padding:0px">
                <h2>Web Hosting</h2>
                <p>You can easily find a web hosting company that offers the right mix of features and price for your applications.</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301867">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>                                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">    
    $('#showDetailsSection').click(function () {

        var $col1 = $('#menu1');
        var $col2 = $('#menu2');

        if ($col1.hasClass('col-lg-36')) {
            $col1.switchClass('col-lg-36', 'col-lg-19');
            $col2.switchClass('col-lg-1', 'col-lg-19');
            $('#menu2Div').show(0);
        }
        else {            
            $col1.switchClass('col-lg-19', 'col-lg-36');
            $col2.switchClass('col-lg-19', 'col-lg-1');
            $('#menu2Div').hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Bootstrap has an event](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) that fires after the collapse is complete. Instead of on `click` for the hide, you could use `hidden.bs.collapse`:

```
$('#showDetailsSection').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
     $('#menu2Div').hide();
});
```